# Comments and notifications

Tags: support, comments, notifications, global-inbox

Sometimes after I have made a comment, I realise it could be better phrased.

If I have missed the ninja-edit window, I copy-paste the comment into a new one, edit that and then delete the old one.

How do notifications work in that situation? Does the person the comment addresses (annoyingly) receive 2 notifications from me? I don't want to be annoying if I can help it. Is the deleted comment still visible for a time or is the notification removed when the comment is deleted?

Just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inbox will contain non-deleted comments only, so it will show only one notification. However, if that person has the Stack Exchange iOS app, he/she will receive two push notifications, as the app is unable to 'retract' outdated notifications.

In general, you shouldn't worry about this. I'd be more likely annoyed by the *content* of a notification than the fact that I would receive two (apparently equal) notifications at once.

@Niall, thanks for testing. Here are the results: two notifications in the mobile app, but only one in the inbox:

[image] [image]

---

[image]

Comment: @Niall if you test these sequence of events on this post, I can edit it to include some screenshots.

Comment: Intentional spelling mistakes included in this comment will be corrected after the ninja-edit window closes. Wait... what spelling mistakes?